# how to click done button of soft keyboard using robotium?

Tags: android, robotium, soft-keyboard

I need to enter some text in an edit text text and after that have to click on the **done** button of the **soft keyboard**. For this I have used the below code

```
solo.sendKey(Solo.ENTER);
```

and

```
solo.clickOnText("Done");
```

but it is not working.how can i click on **done** button in the soft keyboard using **robotium**?

Answer (score 2):

As you know softkey is a bitmap, it can not use key control. What you can do is to know the position and press the position.

Answer (score 2):

Robotium 5.0.1 has a method pressSoftKeyboardNextButton that is defined as:

```
public void pressSoftKeyboardNextButton(){
  final EditText freshestEditText = viewFetcher.getFreshestView(viewFetcher.getCurrentViews(EditText.class));
  if(freshestEditText != null){
    inst.runOnMainSync(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        freshestEditText.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT); 
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The same approach can be applied to invoke the Done button using EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have to do solo.goBack() to close the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
solo.sendKey(16);
```

Actually,

**KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION**

```
public static final int FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION

This mask is used for compatibility, to identify enter keys that are coming from an IME whose enter key has been auto-labelled "next" or "done". This allows TextView to dispatch these as normal enter keys for old applications, but still do the appropriate action when receiving them.
Constant Value: 16 (0x00000010)
```

Comment: Look at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/view/KeyEvent.java#KeyEvent

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to press the **done** button to proceed further. You can give next instruction like `solo.clickOnText("submit")` or something else what is needed, once you have entered the text in edit text.